# WebRTC in Cordova app: WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc

I was using WebRTC in Cordova app with Cordova 5.2.0 and Cordova Android 4.1 without problems. Since I upgraded to Cordova 6.3.1 and Cordova Android 6.1.1, I get the following error message on the console:

```
chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(199)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

The permissions in the Android manifest include the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
```

so I would say everything should be just fine. But still I am getting this error. I also noticed that once I actually try to start streaming my local video, I also get these error messages:

```
[ERROR:voe_audio_processing_impl.cc(685)] SetTypingDetectionStatus: not supported
[WARNING:webrtcvoiceengine.cc(882)] SetTypingDetectionStatus(0) failed, err=8003
[ERROR:audio_manager_android.cc(264)] Unable to select audio device!
[ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(199)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

and this info:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/8430923907866893907' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * gap: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Not sure if the CSP is related to the problem, though. I was trying to fix this, but Meteor (which I am using as a wrapper) won't let me do so.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: Since Android Marshmallow, permissions have to be set programmatically. The settings defined in the manifest are ignored.

I could solve my problem using this Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions